# convert Vector to a single but atypical string in R

Tags: r, string, vector

I have a Question. I would like to convert my vector:

```
x <- c("9781405287623", "9780762100019", "9780007949977", "9780670509386")
```

To get one string:

```
"9781405287623","9780762100019","9780007949977","9780670509386"
```

to be understood well. I want quotation mark to start and close IDs that will be separated by commas. And this has to be one string. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: `paste0('"', paste0(x, collapse = ','), '"')`

Comment: `paste0(sprintf('"%s"', x), colla=",")`